# How to use location object to parse URL without redirecting the page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

The browser has a very efficient URL parser that let you get `location.href`, `hash`, `query`, etc from the current URL. I'd like to use it instead of coding something using regexes.

If you set `location.href` or do `location.replace(url)`, the page gets redirected in Chrome. I tried to get the prototype of location in this browser, but I can't find `location.prototype`. There is a `location.__proto__` which is described as the `Location` class in the js console, but I can't find a way to instantiate it. Plus, I need a cross browser solution and `__proto__` is not available in IE.

If it's not possible, don't give me a regex alternative, just tell me the hard truth, provided you can back it up with evidences.

Comment: +1 for "If it's not possible, don't give me a regex alternative, just tell me the hard truth". It sucks so hard to get to a question with a title like this but then to only get the usual alternatives... Not possible is a good answer in itself. But in this case it's even better because it's not only possible, but *easy*! Yay!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's very much possible! If you create a new `a` object, you can use the location fields without redirecting the browser.

For instance:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "http://openid.neosmart.net/mqudsi#fake"
```

You can now access `.hash`, `.pathname`, `.host`, and all the other location goodies!

```
> console.log(a.host);
openid.neosmart.net
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a generalized version of the wonderful Mahmoud solution:

```
  var parseUrl = (function(){

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "<a></a>";

    return function(url){
      div.firstChild.href = url;
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
      return div.firstChild;
    };

  })();
```

It works that way:

```
var url = parseUrl('http://google.com');
var url = zerobin.parseUrl('http://google.com');
console.log(url.protocol);
"http:"
console.log(url.host);
"google.com"
```

The `parseUrl` code is a bit complicated because IE requires the link HTML code to be processed by its HTML parser if you want it to parse the URL. So we create a closure in which we store a `<div>` with a `<a>` as child (avoid recreating it a each call), and when we need URL parsing, we just take the HTML of `div`, and inject it back to itself, forcing IE to parse it.