# Jquery add class to body from query-string or hash

Tags: jquery, query-string, addclass

I am trying to add a class to the body depending on the url querystring (or hash if thats easier)

If you go to http://www.here.com?myclass I want to page to change the class of the body to: `<body class="myclass">`

This is the closest I got using a hash:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var url=document.URL.split('#')[1];
    if(url == undefined){
        url = '';
    }

    if(url != ''){
        $(document.body).addClass('myclass');
    }
});
```

Comment: This tells how to get the query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901981/add-hash-before-location-pathname/16902458#16902458

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close:

```
var url=document.location
```

or

```
var url=document.location.hash
```

Answer (score 0):

I always like it when I can find the answer here so i will paste it in.

This code of ther is a hash in the url http://www.domain.com# Adds a class of "myclass" to the body tag. Note it ADDS the class not replaces.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var url=document.location.hash;
if(url != ''){
    $(document.body).addClass('myclass');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the query string you want to have add the class, this should work:

```
$(function() {
   if (document.location.href.indexOf('?myclass') > -1 ) {
     $('body').addClass('myclass');
   } 
});
```

Search strings using > -1 or >= 0 to avoid errors.